# Property accesses in v8

Tags: javascript, v8

I want to understand the property accesses in JavaScript programs in v8.

I am looking for property access code in objects.cc in v8. But I am yet not successful in figuring that out. Can someone point to related function or piece of code?

Answer (score 1):

After some debugging, here is the trace of function calls for property access in v8 :

```
 ic/ic.cc : Load 

     objects.cc : GetProperty

        lookup.cc : GetDataValue

             lookup.cc : FetchValue
```

This is the generic flow, based on the kind of properties you are trying to access (for example, array or objects) it may slightly vary.